# How would I freshen up this old door handle for my front door?

Tags: repair, cleaning

[image: Old door handle]

Hi this is the original door handle for my door so I don't want to switch it out (honestly I don't know if I would be able to, might want to if I knew I could) . I was looking for a way that I could make it look more presentable

Comment: It is easy, it is screwed from the other side

Comment: Likely less work to replace it.

Answer (score 4):

Think a brass cleaner would do the best job.  It looks like it is made out of brass.

Start with a small hidden spot to test.

A decent cleaning is all that should be needed to make it look like new.

Comment: yeah, metal polish, then wax or lacquer.